# Can a background image be added to the value of an input field?

Tags: css, input, background-image

I have an input field that looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="CONTINUE" name="submit" class="submitButton">
```

There is a background image on the input that gives it a texture already, so I want to add another background image without overriding the original one.

I have a png of an arrow that needs to display after "CONTINUE" and have tried a few methods to get it on the page including adding an after property in the CSS:

```
input.submitButton:after{.....}
```

as well as trying to put a div inside the value (worth a try) and I can't get it to show.

Is there any way to do this without using absolute positioning?

Comment: 'position:absolute` is the only thing that comes to my mind. Any reason why you want to avoid it?

Comment: I just don't want to go that route if there is a more direct way. thanks!

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir not required, if you want, refer my answer :)

Comment: If you don't really need to use an <input> tag, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the `<button>` tag

[Fiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/4sWcr/3/)

HTML :

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="submitButton">
    Text inside button <span class="spanner">&rarr;</span>
</button>
```

CSS :

```
.spanner {
    background-color:red;
    border-left:4px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do a trick:

```
input.submitButton{
    background: url(arrow.png) 50% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to mention that there is already a repeating background image on the input field itself, so adding a second background image only overrides it.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set a background with arrow + continue

```
input.submitButton{
  /*background-color: transparent;*/
  background-image: url(arrow.png);
  background-position: 50% 100%;
  /*border: none;
  width: ;
  height: ;*/
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: ;
}
```

or you can use a `position:absolute` element with an arrow.